# TIFF IFilter Page Numbers of Result

Tags: sql, full-text-search, tiff, ifilter

We are using the Microsoft TIFF IFilter to OCR documents and store the information in SQL Server 2012 Full Text Search.  Is there any way to configure either the filter or SQL FTS to store the page numbers for which a search results was found?  For example, if I search for "foo", I would like to know that the term "foo" was found on pages 2, 5 and 8.  Is this possible without using a third-party IFilter or FTS engine?